# Adding program to the EExplorer

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, explorer

I was wondering if it was possible to plug my program into the eexplorer for windows. Basically, I want it to open with explorer, and make it so it isn't it's own process. Kind of like how tortoise svn runs in sync with the explorer. This is for c# btw

Comment: What is the "eexplorer"? Are you talking about a shell extension?

Comment: Running inside the explorer process should not be a goal in itself, Tortoise implements IContextMenu and a shell icon overlay for example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are referring to a shell extension. Doing one in C# isn't the most straightforward process but it isn't particularly difficult either. Here is a great CodeProject article on the subject.

[Link and stuff](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1490/Creating-a-shell-extension-with-C)

To my knowledge the code will not be all managed. You will have to access a com assembly but doing so in .NET was graciously made simple by the folks at Microsoft.